# How to bind to DateTime (possibly with one DatePicker and one TextBox)

Tags: wpf, xaml, datetime, datepicker

I am always confused with the type `DateTime`. In our WPF program we have an `DateTime` property exposed by the ViewModel and need to be bind to a Control/Controls in the View. But apparently since the `DateTime` has both Date part and Time part and we'd like to show them both/let the user to modify both. So I think we need one `DatePicker` for date part and one `TextBox` for time part (with format string), but I can't think of the straightforward way to define such Control/Binding in XAML

Googling with "WPF DateTime Binding" doesn't give me many references (why do most of the examples show a binding to DatePicker, when it is obviously a valid requirement to show time as well).

Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) DateTimePicker control;
[image]

You can get this via nuget for your solution. Then simply bind to the value property of the DateTimePicker.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="145*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="31*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="144*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <xctk:DateTimePicker Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding Path=MyDateTime}" Grid.Column="1"/> 
</Grid>
```

VB:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow : Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _myDateTime As DateTime = "#28/04/2014 07:11:00 AM#"

    Public Property MyDateTime As DateTime
        Get
            Return _myDateTime
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)

            If _myDateTime <> value Then

                _myDateTime = value
                OnPropertyChanged("MyDateTime")

            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal PropertyName As String)

        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))

    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        Me.DataContext = Me

    End Sub
End Class
```